# Is it better to drop or update a Mongodb collection to avoid downtime?

Tags: python, sql, mongodb, pymongo, mongodb-atlas

I have a collection that holds metadata for my navigation for a multi-tenant application so it's quite large (8mb).

This needs to be updated regularly and I'm concerned as to what strategy is the best to avoid having my pages breaking because of missing data due to update/drop/recreate operation on a collection?

I'm new to Mongo Atlas and I'm unsure if it's better to drop and recreate or update the collection?

Comment: 8MB is tiny, relatively speaking.  Could you not have a "revision" or "generation" number, then insert your new records as "generation N+1" and delete "generation N"?  As long as your app doesn't use the generation number in its queries, the worst that could happen is it would fetch one old page.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @TimRoberts and I'm thinking out loud but would a work around like saving the new collection first then renaming the old one to 'old' and then renaming the new one with the original collection name work? seems a bit convoluted though

Comment: Is "collection" the Mongo equivalent of a "database"?  As long as that rename can be done atomically, that seems like a workable solution, simpler than what I proposed.

Answer (score 0):

8MB is small, so update should be no problem. Dropping the collection could delay your application, because typically you also have to create indexes.

Important note, if a Mongo client does not find the collection for insert, then a new collection is created automatically. This may conflict with your recreate procedure.